# Issue with nsp scan

Tags: node.js, express, hapi.js, owasp

I am using nsp to scan for vulnerabilities. I see a strange behavior.

In scripts, dependency, devDependency section I have the following content

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "security-scan:nsp": "nsp check --threshold 10 --reporter json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "joi": "10.x",
        "dotenv": "4.0.0",
        "nsp": "3.2.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "lab": "14.x",
        "code": "4.x",
        "eslint": "4.1.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0"
    }
}
```

If I run **npm run security-scan:nsp** i am getting some vulnerability but now if I move the nsp from dependency to devDependency and run **npm run security-scan:nsp** i dont get any vulnerability.Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

Nsp doesn't scan Dev dependencies. The new `npm audit` command does and it uses the same database of vulnerabilities, but doesn't have any of the formatting options of nsp.

Comment: Hey Gangstead, thanks for your answer but my intention here is that nsp module should not go into production, we need it when its in testing stage or dev stage. so thats the reason i want to add it in devDependency, so that in production i can use npm install --only-production